# Websocket to Serial bridge in python getting stuck

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, pyserial

I am working on writing a websocket to serial bridge in Python for which I have used the `websockets` and `pyserial` library.

My ultimate goal is to have a websocket that forwards incoming messages to the serial device and also is constantly reading the serial port for incoming messages and once it reads one (looking for the newline character) also forwards it to the websocket.

My problem is that I cannot make the incoming / outgoing handlers work independantly using asyncio. Reading the serial port is a blocking task which should not be paused, so I run it in an execution pool. This works as I the messages recieved via the serial port are forwarded immediatly to the websocket.

However the incoming messages to the websocket are not being forwarded to the serial port in time. It seems that all the processing is being allocated to reading the serial messages even though I attempted to avoid this via the execution pool. After reading a new serial message all the incoming websocket messages are forwarded to the serial port, instead of them being forwarded immediately.

My code:

`SerialConnection` class

```
from serial import Serial

import asyncio

from .serial_emulator import SerialEmulator

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


class SerialConnection:
    def __init__(self, port, baudrate=115200, timeout=1):
        if port == "test":
            self.connection = SerialEmulator()
        else:
            self.connection = Serial(port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)

        self.reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

    def write(self, data):
        self.connection.write(data)

    async def read(self, size: int = 1):
        return self.connection.read(size)

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()

    @property
    def port(self):
        if self.connection is None:
            return None
        return self.connection.port

    async def read_message(self):
        if self.connection is None:
            return

        async def blocking_read():
            message = b""
            while not message.endswith(b"\n"):
                data = await self.read()
                message += data
            return message.decode().rstrip("\r\n")

        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        message = await loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, blocking_read)
        return await message
```

`WebSocketServer` class:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


class WebSocketServer:
    def __init__(self, port, handler=None):
        self.port = port
        self.server = None
        self.handler = handler or self.handler

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
            print(f"websocket message: {message}, path: {path}")

    async def start(self):
        self.server = await websockets.serve(self.handler, "localhost", self.port)
        await self.server.wait_closed()

    async def stop(self):
        if self.server:
            self.server.close()
            await self.server.wait_closed()

    def run_forever(self):
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.start())
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

`main`

```
import argparse
import asyncio

from websocket_serial_bridge import WebSocketServer, SerialConnection


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("-p", "--websocket-port", type=int, default=8765)

    # add optional argument "list" that when present will list all available serial ports then exit
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", "--list-serial", action="store_true")

    # add optional argument "serial_ports" which will be a list of serial ports to connect to
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--serial-ports", nargs="+", type=str, default=[])

    # add optional argument "test"
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", action="store_true", help="Run in test mode (emulate serial ports).")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    def list_serial_ports():
        import serial.tools.list_ports
        ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        if len(ports) == 0:
            print("No serial ports found")
            return
        for port in ports:
            print(f" - {port.device} - {port.description}")

    if args.list:
        print("Listing serial ports:")
        list_serial_ports()
        return

    websocket_port = args.websocket_port

    serial_ports = args.serial_ports
    if args.test:
        if len(serial_ports) > 0:
            print("Warning: --test specified, ignoring --serial-ports")
        serial_ports = ["test"]

    # if no serial ports specified, list all available serial ports
    if len(serial_ports) == 0:
        print("No serial ports specified, listing all available serial ports:")
        list_serial_ports()
        return

    serial_connections = []
    for serial_port in serial_ports:
        serial_connections.append(SerialConnection(serial_port))

    async def serial_to_websocket(websocket, serial_connection):
        while True:
            serial_msg = await serial_connection.read_message()
            message = f"PORT:{serial_connection.port}|{serial_msg}"
            print(message)
            await websocket.send(serial_msg)

    async def websocket_to_serial(websocket, serial_connection):
        async for websocket_msg in websocket:
            print(f"Received from websocket: {websocket_msg}")
            serial_connection.write(websocket_msg.encode() + b"\n")

    async def handler(websocket, path):
        serial_connection = serial_connections[0]

        await asyncio.gather(
            asyncio.create_task(websocket_to_serial(websocket, serial_connection)),
            asyncio.create_task(serial_to_websocket(websocket, serial_connection)),
        )

    server = WebSocketServer(websocket_port, handler=handler)

    print(f"""Starting websocket server on "ws://localhost:{websocket_port}".""")

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.create_task(server.start())
    loop.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Try to use the [asyncio pyserial implementation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#module-serial.aio)?

Comment: I was not aware of this, I will give it a look, thanks!